# np.zeros in numba? How to make it

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

Hi I have a question about making zero filled array with jit compiler. Mainly I want to make such array:

```
new_state_matrix = np.zeros([state_matrix.shape[0], state_matrix.shape[1]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

I have this error:

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)

No implementation of function Function(<built-in function zeros>) found for signature:
 
 >>> zeros(list(int64)<iv=None>, dtype=class(uint8))
 
There are 2 candidate implementations:
   - Of which 2 did not match due to:
   Overload of function 'zeros': File: numba\core\typing\npydecl.py: Line 511.
     With argument(s): '(list(int64)<iv=None>, dtype=class(uint8))':
    No match.

During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function zeros>)
During: typing of call at C:\Users\d4wt0\Desktop\koderka\MW\proj1\venv\methods.py (850)


File "methods.py", line 850:
def nbh_check(state_matrix, img_matrix, nbh):
    new_state_matrix = np.zeros([state_matrix.shape[0], state_matrix.shape[1]], dtype=np.uint8)
    ^
```

Any ideas how to make it work? Any numba type function or something?

Answer (score 3):

I think passing the shape as a tuple instead of a list could solve the problem. Like so:

```
new_state_matrix = np.zeros((state_matrix.shape[0], state_matrix.shape[1]), dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: Yes, that solves the problem. Even simpler:
`np.zeros(state_matrix.shape[:2], dtype=np.uint8)`